# Firebase Queue Priority

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-queue

I'm new to using [firebase-queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue) for my project and was wondering if there is a way to process data based on an attribute such as priority. 
 **Here is a sample of my data structure.**

```
queue
 tasks
 -L6PGTHyZFbM4eBM66Zt
  -priority : 1
 -L6PGTI3KNj8x_zHqZQX
  -priority : 3
 -L6PGTI6tRceLkaDbfA4
  -priority : 5
```

In this case child `L6PGTI6tRceLkaDbfA4` would be handled before `L6PGTHyZFbM4eBM66Zt & L6PGTI3KNj8x_zHqZQX`

Comment: I don't believe firebase-queue ever works like a priority queue where there is a guaranteed order of processing the items is derived by some property of the items.

Comment: Sounds like an answer Doug. :-)